Where would this star's habitable zone be in AU?
I am making a hypothetical solar system. I want to know where the star's habitable zone would be located (in AU). Here are the characteristics:

Star name: Undecided
Star designation (preliminary): TOI-3173 b
Star Type: M
Spectral Type: M2.5Ve(m)(v). (This star emits emission lines, is rich in metals, and is a variable star.)
Mass: 0.393 Suns
Radius: 0.42 x Sun
Temperature: 3,455°K
Luminosity: 0.02255 Suns
Age: 1.6 Gyr
Variable type: Flare star

The habitable zone parameters are realistic and are in this universe.

To really answer this, information about the planet is also needed (a least size and approx. desired revolving time, if this is fixated). Also: what does the variabel star imply? Is it in a strength that its heat/light emitting characteristics are influenced? -- In general you can say that if your planet system is based on our solarsystem but scaled smaller, the habitable zone also scales linearly with that factor.

Variable star means that it goes through random increases in brightness. I might remove the variable star factors as they may cause confusion. What do you think?

Also check this question to maybe compute/approximate yourself: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246738/habitable-zone-of-this-red-giant?rq=1

Thank you for the extra forums!

I think, I cannot really tell, because your are inventing the world. I/we try to give it "scientific plausibility". But I don't know what are the fix points your story needs. You should maybe add that to the question text.

Thanks. I will add that to the question.

Your question is also likely to be voted for closing due to missing information. Keep in mind: If that happens you are welcome to edit your question and afterwards in can be checked to be reopened. And you can always ask questions here in the comments and stay in contact (Add someone with @... e.g. @Antares if you do, so they receive a notification). Also check out our sandbox which is a good place for newcomers to get help formulationg their questions.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Go to our List of Worldbuilding Resources, scroll down to the "Celestial Mechanics" section and click on the link titled "Habitability/Goldilocks Zone Calculator for Earth-like planets." If that answers your question, please delete this post. If it does not, please explain why the calculator was unable to help you. Thanks. (P.S. keep in mind that a flare star may not have a habitable zone or may not have one that lasts long enough to matter.)

Assuming an earthlike world, you haven't said anything different, this handy calculator gives us 0.14-0.21 AU as a theoretical habitable zone. I would like to note though that for a world orbiting a flare star there is likely no such thing as a habitable zone for surface life, the radiation flux is far too high, even Radiodurans has it's limits, not to mention the longterm effects of frequent, powerful, flares on the atmosphere. So while your world may have shielded ecosystems in deep caves etc... complex surface life is almost certainly a no.
